# Showing evolution of grouping of individuals over different timepoints

Tags: r, ggplot2, flowchart

I am working on a study where we are grouping people in different groups overtime. There are three timepoints and 5 groups in time point 1, 3 groups in time point 2, and 4 groups in time point 3. I would like to built a diagram like this in R that shows the movement of people across different groups overtime.

My data is of the following form:

```
> head(my_data)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  SurID newid profiles
  <fct> <fct> <fct>   
1 1     2     1       
2 2     2     1       
3 3     2     1       
4 1     6     3       
5 2     6     2       
6 3     6     4
```

Where `SurID` is the time point (1, 2 or 3), `newid` is the person's unique identification, and `profiles` is the group they fall in for each timepoint.

I would like to make a graph similar to the one below (done with powerpoint as an example), where we can see how many people fall in each group in each time point, and how many people from each group go to the different groups of the next time point.

[example of graph I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JIFW.png)

I am quite experienced with `ggplot` and have tried playing around but nothing came even close to what I needed - the main issue is with the arrows showing people movements.

Comment: perhaps look into `igraph` package.

Comment: Have you searched for flow charts with r? 

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/06/creating-flowcharts-with-ggplot2/amp/
https://epirhandbook.com/en/diagrams-and-charts.html